# What taxes do I pay for working an event in Mexico?

Tags: united-states, taxes, income, mexico

I live in the U.S. but am holding an event in Mexico. People will pay to attend the event.  How do I claim that income for taxes either in Mexico or the U.S. and what is the process for receiving money and declaring, it, etc?

Comment: On your US tax return you claim it just as any other event, it doesn't matter where you held it. Re Mexico - you'll probably want to talk to a Mexican tax accountant (I'm sure you can find those in some of the US States where there's large Mexican population). There probably is an article in the US-Mexican tax treaty which addresses this kind of one-off event income